# How to rescale trees to extreme shapes?

Tags: r, loops, tree, data-manipulation, phylogeny

I'm posting this again althought @jeremycg helped me to develop the following code. It works but it does perform not what I wanted to!
A quick reminder: I've got a set of trees, that I need to be measured in terms of a factor called gamma and if each tree's value is not in defined range, it gets rescaled until its value is in defined range...  Let's try this example:

```
library(ape)
library(phytools)

trees<- pbtree(b=1, n=100, nsim=50)

 fixmytrees <- function(tree, rescaleamt = NULL){
if(is.null(rescaleamt)){
rescaleamt <- sample(seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1), 1)
} 
if(is.na(gammaStat(tree))){return("bad tree")}
if(gammaStat(tree) < 6){
 return(tree)
 } else {
return(rescale(tree, model ="delta", rescaleamt))
}
}
z<-lapply(tree, fixmytrees) 

 #The script does rescale trees but they are not extreme enough. In this case if you try

 gammaStat(z[[]]) #You would probably see values lower than 6 and sometimes NA!!!
```

Thank You!

Comment: occasional error:                                                                                      longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read libraries and create a recursive helper function:

```
library(ape)
library(geiger)
fixmytrees <- function(tree, rescaleamt = NULL){
  if(is.null(rescaleamt)){
    rescaleamt <- sample(seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1))
  } 
  if(gammaStat(tree) >= 1){
    return(tree)
  } else {
    return(fixmytrees(rescale(tree, "delta", rescaleamt), rescaleamt/2))
  }
}
```

This function will take a tree, and if it passes the gamma check, returns it. If not, it will take a random number from `seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)` and rescale the tree by that amount and call the function again, with the new tree, and `rescaleamt/2`.

So now we just need to do this on your list of trees:

```
lapply(trees, fixmytrees)
```

NB. This is not a particularity sensible thing to do to your data, so please make sure you know why you are doing this.

Comment: Thanks jeremycg! Doesn't it need another loop to go through the list of trees?

Comment: nope, just run the `lapply` command, the output is the fixed trees

Comment: well, since gammaStat only takes phyllo object I thought we need a loop to read trees one by one from the multiplyo object. Perhaps it is why the code still doesn't work, right?

Comment: it returns a list: `z<-lapply(trees, fixmytrees)`, which you can turn into a multiphylo with `class(z) <- "multiPhylo"`

Comment: I posted it again with some modifications!

Comment: yes, you broke the function. The output needs to be recursive. Study the what the previous answer returns, and see why this one is different.

Comment: well, the idea is to do rescaleamt and if still out of range do rescaleamt*2. I guess neither codes are doing this, right?

Comment: no, look at the return statements. There's a much bigger difference than *2 or /2

Comment: let's stick to your original code: when I define more extreme values it does not work: if(gammaStat(tree) >= 5

Comment: try it on z - tree is never modified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97465/discussion-between-jack-and-jeremycg).